# Запоминание N предыдущих значений дискретного сигнала

Tags: matlab

Задан дискретный сигнал, надо упаковывать N отсчетов (создавать вектор) этого сигнала и отправлять на вход функции, которая работает с этим вектором. С помощью чего, как реализовать такое запоминающее устройство на N отсчетов?

Answer (score 1):

[Buffer input signal](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.bufferclass.html)
    % Пример источника:
    hreader=dsp.SignalSource(randn(1024,1),128);

```
% Определяем буфер на 256 отсчетов и пересечение в 128 (по умолчанию 0):
hbuff=dsp.Buffer(256,128);

for i=1:8
     y=step(hbuff,step(hreader));
     % В y 256 отсчетов с 128 отсчетами из прошлого отрезка
 end
```

[Buffer signal vector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/buffer.html)